# MobX React decorators don't work in codepen

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, codepen

i have this mobx and react setup in codepen but the decorator syntax doesn't seem to be working:

https://codepen.io/swyx/pen/OvNmrR

any idea where I might be going wrong? its a very simple setup and i'm "just" following a tutorial.

here's the code for the lazy:

```
const {observable} = mobx;
const {observer, Provider} = mobxReact;
const {Component} = React;

const appState = new class {
  @observable text = "k";
  handleChange = e => this.text = e.target.value;
}

@observer(['store']) // this is erroring! why??
class Form extends Component {
  render() {
    const {handleChange} = this.props.store
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Decorator is an experimental feature which isn't supported by many platforms. I haven't tested on codepen, but **codesandbox** has it supported out of the box. https://codesandbox.io/s/m516xzyk9x If you just want to do some quick testing, this is way easier to get it going.